# Convert a GMT date string to DateTime

Tags: c#

How to convert a string date value of such format:

```
Wed Oct 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

To a date of format of `02/10/2013`.

I have already tried the `DateTime.ParseExact` but it didn't work at all:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateToConvert, "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss GMTzzzzz",    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: It did not work with wich symptoms? Where did you get this string?

Comment: did you miss a d for the day? "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss GMTzzzzz"

Comment: The easiest way to debug pattern is to format some existing date with this pattern and compare.

Comment: @SamWard, having a single `d` is good enough for single/double digit day, *(for parsing)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var dateToConvert = "Wed Oct 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)";
var format =        "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(GMT Daylight Time)'";

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToConvert, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(date); //prints 10/2/2013 2:00:00 AM for my locale
```

You need to specify ending with `'GMT'zzz '(GMT Daylight Time)'`

You can use single `d` in `format` instead of `dd`, works fine

You can check [demo here](http://ideone.com/qX6ALx)

Comment: Single `d` is enough for parsing. Its even safer to use single `d` since it will take care of both, single digit and double digit day.

Comment: `+1` for always I forgot that I can also costumize format part with using `' '`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Is there a way to convert date whether it is in GMT +0100 (GMT DayLight Time), OR in GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Comment: @t_plusplus you can remove that redundant bit via `dateToConvert.Substring(0, dateToConvert.LastIndexOf("GMT") - 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. This is exactly what I have done to resolve the question in the last comment above.

```
int gmtIndex = dateToConvert.IndexOf("G");

string newDate = dateToConvert.Substring(0, gmtIndex).Trim();

value = DateTime.ParseExact(newDate, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```